# Find server IP dynamically

Tags: ios, ping, broadcast, arp

I have a C# server, and an objective-c client working over wifi. Everything is working fine but now I want to detect all computers (or at least, those running my server) on local network, instead of entering the IP manually.
I've read some posts about that, they recommend to do a broadcast to find the IP or to read ARP table or to ping every IP adresses between xx.xx.xx.0 to 255.

What is the best way to do that and how ? I really don't know where to begin or how to do that. Do you have some tutorials or example ? I can't find anything usefull in objective-c. I don't want to use the Bonjour service since my server works on windows.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You say you don't want to use Bonjour because your server runs on Windows - have you looked into the [Bonjour SDK](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/)? It has Windows libraries in various languages.

Comment: No I didn't. I will take a look, I thought I needed to have bonjour service installed on windows side that's why.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a echoing system on the server on a specific port say 8070

i have done Broadcast of message to a given port using following code.

```
broadCastSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
if ([broadcastSocket enableBroadcast:true error:&error] == false) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to enable broadcast, Reason %@:",[error userInfo]);
}
NSData *data = [QueryString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[broadcastSocket sendData:data toHost:@"255.255.255.255" port:8070 withTimeout:-1 tag:5];
```

your all the server will receive data on the port and echoing system reply to given port. Now you can listen to those port and get the ip of all the server which will reply.and ofcourse this trick will only work if sever is yours.
**NOTE ::** I was using [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) Library but you can use whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. Broadcast IP is always 255.255.255.255 ?

Comment: yes. broadcasting to this ip will send message to all ip in network

Comment: Broadcasting is almost always the wrong answer though, particularly so on large networks because of the amount of network traffic that can be generated if you have a large number of servers and clients.  A better approach is to use one of the standardized service discovery protocols like Bonjour or SSDP.  In this specific case the best bet is probably Bonjour because implementing it is trivial on iOS and relatively easy on your windows server.

Comment: Me again, I've read the doc of GCDAsyncSocket and I just realized that I didn't told you that my server is using TCP protocol. TCP can't accept broadcast right ? So is it still possible to get the server IP by broadcasting and how ? Should I set an UDP listener in my server and then switch back to TCP when I've got the serv IP ? Thanks again for your help, I'm still a beginner in programming.

Comment: Woops didn't saw your answer David. I don't know anything about Bonjour service. I'll try to read some doc then if it's a better way to do that.

Comment: @user1451884 you don't have to modify any of your existing mechanism (TCP or anything) in your server. just add a udp based echoing system in the server. and use same in your client. this is how i have implemented in my application where i was also searching for the server on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bonjour SDK which you can find in Visual Studio by `Refereces->Right Click -> Add References -> COM tab -> Bonjour SDK or Apple Bonjour SDK`. Then you can use Bonjour SDK's methods to scan  intranet.